# If $H$ has the same (finite) order as $G$, then any surjective map is necessarily injective.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> If $H$ has the same (finite) order as $G$, then any surjective map is necessarily injective.

From Dummit and Foote 3 ed., page 39.

A line in the text and not sure why it is true. If more information is needed, I can edit my post and add the more of the paragraph, or link the post to a pdf copy of the textbook.

Comment: Imagine a function between two finite sets of the same size. Suppose the map is surjective, but not injective. In other words, there are at least two elements in the domain which have the same image in the codomain. What does this say about the size of the image of the function? Can you find a contradiction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the cardinalities of the two groups $G,H$ be equal and finite and let $\varphi:H \rightarrow G$.  If $\varphi$ is not surjective, then by the Pigeonhole principle, there is some $g \in G$ which is the image of more than one element of $H$, making $\varphi$ not injective.  If $\varphi$ is not injective, then by the Pigeonhole principle, there is at least one element of $G$ that is not the image of any element of $H$, making $\varphi$ not surjective.  Therefore $\varphi$ injective $\iff$ $\varphi$ surjective.

Answer (score 2):

[Injectivity and surjectivity of a map from a finite set to itself are equivalent conditions.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_set#Basic_properties) The fact that it's a group doesn't contribute anything, it's just a basic fact about finite sets.

Answer (score 2):

If $H$ and $G$ are finite groups, then the sets $H$ and $G$ are also finite. If there exists a surjection $f:H\to G$, then that means that every element in $G$ is mapped to by $f$. i.e. $\forall g \in G, \exists h \in H$ s.t. $f(h) = g$.

So if $f$ is surjective, why is $f$ necessarily injective? Because $f$ is only **not** injective if there are two or more elements in $H$ that map to the same element of $G$, i.e. if $f$ is not injective, then $\exists h, h' \in H$ s.t. $f(h) = f(h')$ but $h \neq h'$. However, if $H$ is surjectively mapped onto $G$, and $|G| = |H|$, then we don't have any further elements remaining in $H$ that we can map onto $G$. This is really just an application of the pigeon-hole principle if you think about it.